# React-player play videos automatically when loaded without controls

Tags: reactjs, cloudinary, react-player

Im using react-player with cloudinary to automatically play and loop a video without controls (so it looks like a gif).

Preferences currently set to:

```
<ReactPlayer 
    url={elem.media_path}
    playing={true} 
    loop={true} 
    controls={false}
/>
```

The video wont play until it has loaded unless controls are on and you start it manually.

Is it possible to automatically start the video without controls?

Answer (score 6):

Depends on browser which you are using but video must be `muted` if you want to `autoplay` without users interaction.

> Chrome's autoplay policies are simple:
>
> - **Muted autoplay is always allowed**.
> - Autoplay with sound is allowed if:
>
>   - User has interacted with the domain (click, tap, etc.).
>   - On desktop, the user's Media Engagement Index threshold has been crossed, meaning the user has previously played video with sound.
>   - The user has added the site to their home screen on mobile or installed the PWA on desktop.
> - Top frames can delegate autoplay permission to their iframes to allow autoplay with sound.

You can read more about it at [Google Developers - Autoplay Policy Changes](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes)

Comment: Excellent answer.. especially the "Media Engagement Index" can cause a lot of head-scratching. (first it works, then it doesn't). Is there a way to see what the index actually is?

Comment: @Kokodoko If you would like to see your MEI in Chrome browser you can check it at `chrome://media-engagement/` (URL).

Comment: Wow! never knew about this.

Comment: Thanks you, that's incredibly helpful!